# There is an old library that doesn't have a build for scala 2.13.x, how to create local maven repository lookup?

Tags: scala, sbt

I want to locally build a library in scala 2.13.x and have my sbt dependencies search my local repository for now since the published repo currently doesn't support 2.13.x

Do I have to add a special resolver to look locally so my sbt build can find the library built in the scala version I need?

Comment: check `sbt publishLocal`. It will publish project to a local Ivy repository (By default `${user.home}/.ivy2/local`). Not sure if you need to change version or it will prefer local over glaobal... you need to check that.

Comment: @Scalway a common trick is to publish a new version, that way SBT will always prefer the local, it is also a good idea because that way your build will fail in other parts. Now, another common thing to do would be to fork the library and publish a new release so you do not need to depend on a local jar as well as making the new version available for everyone :)

Comment: If you are testing locally you can use `-SNAPSHOT` prefix in your version. This way sbt will regularly check if it has the newest version instead of assuming that version is immutable like all normal releases. But once you make sure that it works, you should have it published in some artifactory without `-SNAPSHOT`.